# Adding error bars on x axis in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

Is it possible to add error bars in the x direction in a `DateListPlot`? It seems that a naive application of `Around` in this case makes Mathematica really mad...

I need to add error bars of 1 day (12 hours on the left and 12 hours on the right) to each day. Here are some of my data:

```
count = {3457, 3457, 3340, 3356, 3284, 3197, 3212, 3224, 3245, 3258, 3328, 3308};
date = {2016, 11, 21, 12, 0, 0};
time = NestList[DatePlus[#, Quantity[1, "Day"]] &, date, Length@count - 1];
```

Without the error bars I use the following for the plot:

```
TS=Transpose[{time,count}];
DateListPlot[TS]
```

I have tried to do the following:

```
time2=time;
ad = Around[time[[All, 4]], 12];
time2[[All, 4]] = ad;
TS2 = Transpose[{time2, count}];
DateListPlot[TS2]
```

but I get a bunch of errors.

If needed, my version is `"13.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 29, 2022)".`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
Show[DateListPlot @ TS, 
 ListLinePlot[{Around[AbsoluteTime @ #, 12 60 60], #2} & @@@ TS]
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"